# Laravel 6 with Digital Ocean Managed Redis

Tags: laravel, redis, digital-ocean

I'm having trouble connecting to my managed DO Redis db, and cannot find any accounts of it being successfully used. Has anyone had experience with this and could shed some light on it?

I've changed the database credentials, cleared the config etc, but get

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Call to a member function connect() on null
```

Comment: Can you add more details and what you tried? I really don't understand "connecting to my managed DO Redis db". Do you have an ubuntu and you want to setup redis inside it?

Comment: I have a redis database on digital ocean, but my laravel application cant connect to it given the credentials.